# Java curl response

Tags: java, json, curl, processbuilder

I have a curl command used with java ProcessBuilder. The curl command returns the following JSon example on the command line:

```
{"Token":{"urlString":"JAAIZ2phZWhybGkIZ2phZWhybGkAigFZ1UOgr4oBWflQJK}}
```

Using the following java code, reading the line is always empty and I do not understand why.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "-k", "-negotiate", "-s", "-u", ":", "https://host:port/webhdfs/v1/?op=GETDELEGATIONTOKEN&renewer", "=", "user");

Process p = pb.start();

InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

String line = new String();

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("read line from curl command: " + line);
    responseStrBuilder.append(line);
}
```

Comment: just try once InputStream is = p.getErrorStream() and check whether you are getting anything as error or not.

Comment: If all you want is to perform an HTTP request, [why not use `URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, there is no error. Switching to InputStream is = p.getErrorStream(); returns an empyt stream.

Comment: if I include -i in the curl command ""curl", "-i", "-k" .... than I get back the header. So curl retruns something and the InputStream etc. is working. But the message as Json I never get.

Answer (score 0):

The command was wrong. An additional - was missing before negotiate:

```
curl -k --negotiate
```